# Android fragment to fragment transition right to left, top to bottom issue

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-transitions

MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity which is simply acts a container.

MainFragment which have the toolbar, tablayout, viewpager and navigation drawer.

SecondFragment to have its own toolbar and another fragment container.

MainActivity with the MainFragment looks like this. When click on the one of the button in the tab fragment, i want the another fragment to transition from right to left and back with left to right. 
[image]

This image is animation from right to left. The main fragment drops the height during the animation like in the red box.

[image]

When click back on detail fragment, The animation from left to right, it becomes a bit higher and overlaps with the statusbar in the detail fragment.

[image]

Also the voice fragment which animates from bottom to top and back with top to bottom. It overlaps with statusbar when animation stops.

[image]

```
        fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.bottom_to_top_enter, R.anim.bottom_to_top_exit, R.anim.top_to_bottom_enter, R.anim.top_to_bottom_exit);

        fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.right_to_left_enter, R.anim.right_to_left_exit, R.anim.left_to_right_enter, R.anim.left_to_right_exit);
```

bootm_to_top_enter.xml

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate
        android:duration="3000"
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="100%"
        android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="0%" />
</set>
```

bottom_to_top_exit.xml

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate
        android:duration="3000"
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="-100%" />
</set>
```

top_to_bottom_enter.xml

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate
        android:duration="3000"
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="-100%"
        android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="0%" />
</set>
```

top_to_bottom_exit.xml

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate
        android:duration="3000"
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="100%" />
</set>
```

right_to_left_enter.xml

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <translate
        android:duration="3000"
        android:fromXDelta="100%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="0%" />
</set>
```

right_to_left_exit.xml

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:duration="3000"
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="-100%"
        android:toYDelta="0%" />
</set>
```

left_to_right_enter.xml

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:duration="3000"
        android:fromXDelta="-100%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="0%" />
</set>
```

left_to_right_exit.xml

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:duration="3000"
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="100%"
        android:toYDelta="0%" />
</set>
```

Does anyone have any idea how this happens?

Thanks a lot.